# Getting robotic and chopped audio when using EZOutput

Tags: ios, swift, audio, audio-streaming, ezaudio

I am using EZOutput from [EZAudio](https://github.com/syedhali/EZAudio) to output sound I receive from a stream of audio (self.myAudioBufferList). Think LiveListen. I also have the audio basic description (self.asbd!). However when I set the shouldFill method of the EZOutput datasource, I get a robotic version of the sound that is chopped with some of it missing.

```
func output(_ output: EZOutput!, shouldFill audioBufferList: UnsafeMutablePointer<AudioBufferList>!, withNumberOfFrames frames: UInt32, timestamp: UnsafePointer<AudioTimeStamp>!) -> OSStatus {
    
    if self.asbd != nil {
        output.inputFormat = self.asbd!
    }
    
    if self.audioBufferList != nil {
        audioBufferList.pointee.mNumberBuffers = self.myAudioBufferList!.mNumberBuffers
        audioBufferList.pointee.mBuffers.mNumberChannels = self.myAudioBufferList!.mBuffers.mNumberChannels
        audioBufferList.pointee.mBuffers.mData = self.myAudioBufferList!.mBuffers.mData
    } else {
        print("it is nil, and that is why it is making low noise")
        audioBufferList.pointee.mBuffers.mData = nil
    }
    
    return noErr;
}
```

Also when is set the audioBufferList mDataByteSize, the quality gets worse. In it's current configuration the dataByteSize is 4096 where as myAudioBufferList is not constant and fluctuates, never going over 512.

```
audioBufferList.pointee.mBuffers.mDataByteSize = self.myAudioBufferList!.mBuffers.mDataByteSize
```

The frames value that the datasource method gives has a value of 1024.

Note: I have also tried providing the inputFormat when creating an instance of EZOutput, however this does nothing to improve the sound

```
// Assign a delegate and datasource to the shared instance of the output to provide the output audio data
self.ezOutput = EZOutput.init(dataSource: self, inputFormat: asbd)
self.ezOutput?.delegate = self
```

Comment: In order to get the answer you're looking for, I expect you will need to explain how myAudioBufferList is filled. Almost certainly, the underlying solution involves changes to that code as much or more than in the code you've shown. The key point is that you must have the frames available when they are requested. Obviously a more complete example that would allow people to reproduce your problem would be ideal, but a fuller explanation of how you get frames is likely a necessary first step.

Comment: @RobNapier, I have included how myAudioBufferList is filled, I agree it is needed for more clarity. I did not include it initially to avoid complexity as it includes reading from a circular buffer for memory issues.

Comment: It's been a while since I've looked at TPCircularBuffer code, but this doesn't look right. I would recommend using (or at least consulting) TPCircularBufferDequeueBufferListFrames to make sure you're aligning your samples correctly. I also recommend adding debug logic to your `output()` callback to validate that you are always able to fill the buffers. It's possible that your producing side is getting behind, and you have no logic here to handle that situation. Your circular buffer may be too small.

Comment: There is more code that has been abstracted for the Circular Buffer, again to avoid more complexity. The audio recording works without any problems or frames missing. It is only when I output the sound to the speaker that the issue arises.

Comment: Outputting to a file is not a real-time operation. You can wait for the frames to show up if something is getting behind. If you're a bit out of sync with real-time operations (like providing audio to the speaker), then you will drop frames often which matches your symptoms. That is why I recommend the debugging steps I've recommended. There are many things that can be the *root* cause of your problem (which is why I can't debug it without seeing all the code, at which point this turns into consulting rather than SO), but the *final* cause sounds like dropped frames.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not particularly familiar with EZAudio, but the callback seems to be requesting a specific number of frames, and you seem to be ignoring that. If it asks for 1024 frames, you must fill precisely 1024 frames before returning (unless you're at the end of data, in which case you'd pad and post EZAudioPlayerDidReachEndOfFileNotification). If you don't have 1024 frames, then you'll either need to block until you do, signal an underrun (not sure how EZAudio does this), or fabricate "appropriate" data to fill (for example, Packet Loss Concealment). If you're getting data in blocks of irregular sizes, then you may need to buffer a bit.

"Robotic" or other types of noise are very often due to mismatched waveforms. (This translates into high-frequency noise.) In this code, that can be due to dropping good data or due to inserting zeros for missing data.